# how to plot gps coordinates on my own raster map?

Tags: raster, gps, tiles

I have lat log values available in degree format, i donot know how to access raster maps using c#, and how to plot accurately.

which libraries should i use and what are the controls avialable ,i am using visual studio 2010 ultimate edition. There are controls available for vector maps in which one can zoom ,pan and plot the given coordinates accurately etc etc, but i have a georeferenced raster map with 4000*5000 resolution, i have done tiling with the map,each tile is of 256*256 resolution i need some source code or a manual to use the raster map to develop a navigation app and to plot the location accuraetly on the map, thanks

Comment: Being a more programmatical question, if you don't get an answer you may be better suited to stackoverflow.

Comment: Have u been able to plot?? What's the progress..?? Can u share your contact details... I m working on a similar project... May like to share.. thx

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133600)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133600)

Answer (score 1):

Codeplex should be your first start.  SharpMap is on NuGet which will be accessable from your IDE.

The link is this: http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

The framework is adaptable, but you might need to dive into the code a little to tune what you need.